# How can I convert my state from an object into a mappable array?

Tags: reactjs

[My "Card Dealer" in CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcarddealer-forked-3b7pp?file=/src/CardDeck.jsx)

I was watching a coding challenge done in React with class based components that extracts data from a "card deck API" using Axios. Once you have the deck and the deck ID, you can then render a separate "Card" component that displays the current card and all previous cards.

Rather than use classes, I decided to try this challenge using hooks instead. Due to poor planning, my state is pretty much one big object, and I can't map over it to display multiple "Card" components. I only get the current stateless "child"card displayed at the moment.

How can I change the way I have my state structured so I can map over it to display the "image" prop for all the cards that were previously dealt to display simultaneously? Thanks for any input!

I wanted to be able to do something like:

```
    let card = deck.map((c) => {
    return (
    <Card image={c.img} value={c.value} />
    )
    });


//My current code:

     import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import axios from "axios";


function CardDeck() {
  let [deck, setDeck] = useState([]);


  useEffect(() => {
    
    let shuffle = async () => {
      let response = await axios.get(
        "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle"
      );
      let data = response.data;

      setDeck({
        id: data.deck_id,
        remaining: data.remaining,
        shuffled: data.shuffled
    });
    };
    shuffle();
  }, []);

  let getCard = async () => {
    
    const url = `https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${deck.id}/draw/`;
    let response = await axios.get(url);
    let card = response.data.cards;

    if (response.data.success) {
      setDeck((prev) => {
        console.log(deck.drawn);
        
        
        return {
          ...prev, 
          img: card[0].image,
          remaining: response.data.remaining,
          name: `${card[0].value} of ${card[0].suit}`,
          code: card[0].code,
        };
      });
    }
  };



  return  (
    <div>
    <h1>Card Dealer</h1>
    <button onClick={getCard}>Get Card!</button>
    <h3>{deck.name}</h3>
        <Card
        deckID={deck.id}
        remaining={deck.remaining}
        drawn={deck.drawn}
        image={deck.img}
        name={deck.name}
        id={deck.code}
      />
    {deck.remaining === 0 && <button>New Deck</button>}
  </div>
  )
  
  
}

export default CardDeck;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output:

[image: cards Output]

Here I am storing all the fetched cards in `card` and then iterating it to show them in a row.

Hope this gives you an idea.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Card from "./Card";
import axios from "axios";

function CardDeck() {
  let [cardDeck, setCardDeck] = useState({});
  const [card, setCard] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    let shuffle = async () => {
      let response = await axios.get(
        "https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/new/shuffle"
      );
      let data = response.data;
      // console.log(data);
      setCardDeck({
        id: data.deck_id,
        remaining: data.remaining,
        shuffled: data.shuffled
      });
    };
    shuffle();
  }, []);

  let getCard = async () => {
    const url = `https://deckofcardsapi.com/api/deck/${cardDeck.id}/draw/`;
    let response = await axios.get(url);
    let newCard = response.data.cards;
    // console.log(newCard);
    let temp = [...card];
    temp.push(newCard);

    console.log(card);
    if (cardDeck.remaining > 0) {
      setCard(temp);
    }
    console.log(cardDeck);
  };

  return !cardDeck.remaining ? (
    <div>
      <h1>Game Over! Out of cards...</h1>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div>
      <h1>Card Dealer</h1>
      <button onClick={getCard}>Get Card!</button>

      <div
        style={{
          display: "flex",
          flexWrap: "wrap",
          flexDirection: "row",
          width: "100%"
        }}
      >
        {card.map((c) => (
          <img key={c[0]["image"]} src={c[0]["image"]} alt="card" width={60} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CardDeck;
```

Working Code: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactcarddealer-forked-vjpc4?file=/src/CardDeck.jsx:0-1673)

Comment: Ok, gotcha. So, set a second piece of state that just keeps track of a new "card array", then use that array to iterate over in order to display the <Card /> component. Sounds like a plan! Thanks!

Comment: Just did. Thank you!